# Equivalence between a double integration and Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I was reading a paper and they claim the following.
Suppose 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(\lambda x + \theta) d\mu(x) = 0,
$$
where $\mu$ is a signed Borel measure, $g$ is continuous and in $S'(\mathbb{R})$. Here $S(\mathbb{R})$ is the Schwartz space, and $S'(\mathbb{R})$ is its dual. 
Let $w(\theta) \in S(\mathbb{R})$.
Then,
$$
(1) \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}} w(\theta)d\theta \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(\lambda x + \theta) d\mu(x) = 0,
$$
that I interprete it as 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left[w(\theta) \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(\lambda x + \theta) d\mu(x)\right] d\theta = 0.
$$
By setting $u = \lambda x + \theta$, and change order of integration, the paper claim that the above is
$$
(2) \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(u) \int_{\mathbb{R}} w(\theta) d\mu(\frac{u-\theta}{\lambda}) = 0,
$$
that I am not sure what is means.
It is claimed that the above is equivalent to 
$$
(3) \quad \hat{g}(\hat{w}(\cdot)\widehat{d\mu}(\lambda \cdot)) = 0,
$$
where $\hat{g}$ is the Fourier transform of $g$ in the sense of tempered distribution.

I am not sure how (2) and (3) are equivalent and what these mean.

Any comments/suggestions/answers will be very appreciated.

Comment: @kimchilover Forgot to mention that. $g$ is continuous and in $S'(\mathbb{R})$. Also $\mu$ is a signed borel measure.

Comment: @kimchilover Just edited.